# how to pass the destroyed state of an object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my destroy game object works in my game but whenever I change scenes then return back to the scene where I destroyed the object, it is there again. how do i make it stay destroyed? do i have to deserialize it? i don't need it to creat a save file. i just need the destroyed object to not appear again.

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
     i.AddItem(0);
     nameobj = gameObject.name;
     Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: that is my code on the object to be destroyed

Comment: Similar question asked multiple times. You need to learn how to save data between scenes in a persistent manner (Serialization).
Check this article : http://naplandgames.com/blog/2016/11/27/saving-data-in-unity-3d-serialization-for-beginners/

Comment: Additional to managing data between multiple scenes, you should check how to add scenes in additive way and remove them from stack while going back. This way previous scene will be in memory which is a overhead but serves the purpose for many use case https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static class DestroyedObjects 
{ 
    static List<GameObject> objs = new List<GameObject>();
    public static void Add(GameObject obj) 
    {
        if(!objs.Contains(obj))
            objs.Add(obj); 
    } 
}
```

And use it like:

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    i.AddItem(0);
    nameobj = gameObject.name;
    DestroyedObjects.Add(gameObject);
    // Destroy(gameObject);
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: i will try this. thanks for the answer!

Comment: it has an error sir. it says cannot declare instance members in static class

Comment: @JrRosales fixed.

Comment: thanks for the answer sir. but one more question, how do i make the DestroyedObjects class check the scene at every load to hide the destroyed object? where do i attach it?